# Xamarin.forms : Integrate Okta SSO with ws-federation

Tags: xamarin.forms, single-sign-on, okta, ws-federation, okta-api

In our Xamarin.forms app, we want to support SSO with OKTA. By using link https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/05/01/add-authentication-xamarin-openid-connect, we were able to implement SSO feature but using "OpenId Connect" (not WS-Federation).

My question here is can we integrate OKTA SSO with WS-Federation in Xamarin.Forms? If 'Yes' any help link is appreciated here.

Comment: 0

you could look at this and maybe help you https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Apps/Office%20365/Apps_Configure_Okta%20Template_WS_Federation.htm?cshid=ext_Apps_Configure_Okta_Template_WS_Federation